# Change an ImageView height in Android Studio

Tags: string, android-studio, integer, imageview

I have an app I am building in Android Studio.  I get a value from MQTT and want to use the value to change the height of an imageView.
My imageView is

```
val imagea = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)
```

and the value I get from my MQTT feed is

```
val msgl = "${message.toString()}"
```

How can I change the string to a int and then how do I change the height of the imageView2?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to an integer, use `parseInt`. You'll want to wrap it in a try/catch block to handle any issues with the input string.

```
try {
    imageHeight = Integer.parseInt(msgl);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
   [Error handling here]
}
```

To set the height of an ImageView programmatically:

```
imagea.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight
```

Note: if you have already initiated the layout of the activity before you have the input string, you will need to re-inflate it with this:

```
imagea.requestLayout();
```